# Build Grails project with specific environment

Tags: gradle, grails, build, environment

After migrating my project from Grails 3.1.8 to Grails 6.1.0, the build fails with error :

./gradlew clean build -x test -Dgrails.env=preprod

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task '.env=preprod' not found in root project 'showcase'.

Versions used :
grailsVersion=6.1.0
gradleWrapperVersion=7.6

Why gradlew doesn't recognize the property env of grails ?